# How to determine region event on list of beacon on android

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon-android

I am using beacon from Sensoro, in iOS SDK I can monitor a region, and the SDK can tell me the entering and exiting events by implementing :

```
- (void)beaconManager:(SBKBeaconManager *)beaconManager didDetermineState:(SBKRegionState)state forRegion:(SBKBeaconID *)region;
```

in Android SDK there is no functionality about this event, i have contacted the support but there is no response from their developer, just their product marketing support, so maybe there is an idea at least a similar way to get event when user leaving/entering the region. I get stuck on there, because for example there is a 100 beacon in region 'A', and user event is entering this region, and there is also 10 beacon of region 'B', so user entering this region too, so when i must triggered for leaving region of region 'A' or 'B' ? so I think there is so much process on there to check one by one every update. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there anything specific about the Sensor SDK that you need to use?  As far as I know, they are standard iBeacon transmitters, so you can use any beacon SDK. On iOS, CoreLocation provides a `didDetermineState:forRegion:` callback, and  on Android the [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/) provides an equivalent `didDetermibeStateForRegion` callback.

To use these SDKs, you just need to know your Sensoro beacon's ProximityUUID to start beacon monitoring.

Comment: Thanks @davidgyoung , you saved my day, I really new with beacon, I think each beacon product just have a bundle SDK they provide, but evidently i can use other SDK.

Comment: when I implemented `@Override
            public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {` , why always give null value in Region? because i need major value, or I missing something?

Comment: The region in the callback is a copy of the region you used to set up monitoring.  You probably started monitoring without specifying the major and minor.  If you want to read the major and minor identifiers without specifying them as part of your region, you need to use the ranging API, which will call `locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion)` with an array of beacons with the specific major and minor fields populated.